# Add class based on site

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am inlcuding my navigation with php: `<?php include('navigation.php');?>`. Based on which site the user is the style of the navigation shall change. Therefore I need to add a class to the `<li>` element of my navigation.

I thought on making a switch statement on the `$(document).ready` function. But how can I get the called site to add the class at the correct `<li>`? Or is there a better best practice for my problem?

**navigation.php**

```
<div id="menu">
        <div class="pure-menu pure-menu-open">

        <ul>
            <li id="lielem1"><a href="#">Elem1</a></li>
            <li id="lielem2"><a href="#">Elem2</a></li>             
            <li id="lielem3" class="menu-item-divided pure-menu-selected">
                <a href="#">Elem3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In this scenario, I've think that the best practice would be that you should in your navigation.php at which page you currently are, and output the class directly to the li. With $_SERVER you can probably find what page you currently at.

Comment: paste ur html and what u tried so far ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To apply "class-for-login" class on /login page you do:

```
<li id="lielem1" class="<?php echo $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI] == "/login" ? "class-for-login-page" : ""; ?>">Elem1</li>
```